# php rewrite rule

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i know basicly how to use php rewrite engine, but...

this is my rewrite rule

the url is;
http://www.mypage.com/galeri.php?id=3

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^galeri/([^/]*)$ /galeri.php?id=$1 [L]
```

and the result is;
http://www.mypage.com.tr/galeri/3

it works fine, but i have to change all url parameters inside the pages like;
from

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.min.js?ver=1.4.2'></script>//from this to...
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://mypage.com/js/jquery.min.js?ver=1.4.2'></script>
```

i'm sure there is an easy way to do this but how?

---

Guys thank you for your answers but i guess i have to make the question clear;

let's say there is an image tag inside tha page like;

**src="uploads/image.png"**

the page will seach the file inside **galeri/3/uploads/image.png** because of the rewrite url.Is there a way to ignore the rewrite url and look for the files on  root directory?

Comment: <head>
        <base href="http://mywebsite.com/" />
    </head>

i've found a solution to change all physical url's inside the page.
Thanks for your interests.

Answer (score 0):

Change the rule to this:

```
RewriteRule ^galeri/([0-9]+)$ /galeri.php?id=$1 [L]
```

This will only allow numeric IDs. Things like scripts will not be affected because they have letters.

Answer (score 0):

With a RewriteCond

**From:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^galeri/([^/]*)$ /galeri.php?id=$1 [L]
```

**To**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^galeri/([^/]*)$ /galeri.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Kolink is also right, if you expect only numbers then rewrite only numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend including it as a PHP file with get_file_contents and using

```
<?php
 $file = file_get_contents("JSFILE.js");
?>
```

Then parse it with PHP http://forums.digitalpoint.com/showthread.php?t=1136535

Comment: Will this embed the content of the javasscript inside the html? If so, it will produce a lot of traffic.